# Functional equation - unique solution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

A twice differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is given such thah $f(0) = 1$, $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$ and $f(f(x)) = 4x - 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. One such function is $f(x) = -2x + 1$. I wonder if there is another function satisfying the given equation and conditions. Can anyone help?

Comment: $f$ must be one-to-one, and $f(1)=f(f(0))=-1$ so $f$ must be strictly decreasing.

Comment: I have proven that. But how it helps me?

Comment: It helps if you tell us what you know. You are asking us to volunteer help you, it is irritating if you waste our time.

Comment: Differentiating both sides of $f(f(x)) = 4x-1$ we get $f'(f(x))\,f'(x)=4$. Substituting $x$ with $f(x)$ in the last expression we get $f'(4x-1)\,f'(f(x))=4$. Putting them together yields $f'(x)=f'(4x-1)$. Hence the derivative of $f$ is differentiable and invariant under an affine transformation

Comment: Since $f'(x)$ is continuous, and $f'(x) = f'(x/4 + 1/4)$, then that means that $f'(x)=f'(1/3)$, a constant.

Comment: Thomas that wasn't done in purpose. I thought that it wasn't leading anywhere. My mistake. Anyway, I have shown that $f \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) = 0$, $f (1) = -1$ and that $f$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: @framago I am not familiar with affine transformations, so could you be more specific please?

Comment: the affine function $h(x) = 4x-1$ can be written as $ h(x)-1/3 = 4(x-1/3)$. This means the function multiplies by 4 the distance from $1/3$. Now you have that $f'(x+1/3) = f'(h(x+1/3) ) = f'(4x +1/3)$. Substituting $4x=y$ you have $f'(y-1/3) = f'(y/4 -1/3)$. Iterating you get $f'(y +1/3) = f'( y/4^n +1/3)$. Taking the limit for $n \to \infty$ and using continuity you have $f'(y+1/3) =f'(1/3) = c$. Finally using $f(x) = cx+d$ in zero and 1 you get your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution is in the comments. I'll just put them together.**

$f^2$ is injective. From that it's easy to show that $f$ is also injective. $f(1)=f(f(0))=-1<f(0)$, this along with being injective says that $f$ is strictly decreasing. Since $f$ is differentiable it follows that  for all x
\begin{equation}
f'(x) \leq 0  \hspace{4cm} (1)
\end{equation}
Now differentiating $f(f(x))=4x-1$ with respect to $x$
\begin{equation}
f'(f(x))f'(x)=4  \hspace{2.6cm} (2)
\end{equation}
Replacing $x$ with $f(x)$ in $(2)$ we get
\begin{equation}
f'(4x-1)f'(f(x))=4  \hspace{1.7cm} (3)
\end{equation}
From $(2)$ and $(3)$ one get $f'(x)=f'(4x-1)$ where again substituting $x$ by $\frac{x+1}{4}$ we get
\begin{align}
 f'(x)&=f'(\frac{x}{4}+\frac{1}{4}) \\
      &=f'(\frac{x}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4}) \\
      &=f'(\frac{x}{4^3}+\frac{1}{4^3}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4}) \\
      &= \cdots ~~\cdots ~~\cdots \\
      &=f'(\frac{x}{4^n}+\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{4^i})~~~~~~~~~~~(\textit{after the}~n^{th}\textit{th}~\textit{equality})
\end{align}
Now taking limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, since $f'$ is continuous we obtain for all $x$ that $f'(x)=f'(\frac{1}{3})=a'$     $\hspace{0.5cm}$ (say). This implies (by integrating) $f(x)=a'x+b'$  for some real constant $b'$. From $(1)~~~f'(x) \leq 0$ and  $f(0)=1$ implies $a' \leq 0$ and $b'=1$. $a'=0$ is not an option since we have $f^2(x)=4x-1$. Let $a'=-a$ where $a>0$. Then $f(x)=-ax+1$. Now $f(f(x))=4x-1$ gives (equating coefficient of $x$ and the constant term) $a=2$.  So $f(x)=-2x+1$ is the unique function with the said properties.

Comment: It probably does not affect your solution, but with respect to (1) note that $f'(x)$ can be zero (at some points) for a strictly decreasing function. $f(x)= -x^3$ is the standard example with $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Right. I've incorporated that.